# How can I group (by) two joined tables

Tags: oracle, join, group-by

How can I group (by) two joined tables (in an Oracle database) like this:

```
cant:
id      CANT_VAL    COD_VAL
18059   18.56       R12
18060   11          R10
18061   15          R11

col:
FK_ID_COL_DMA   CANT_VAL    COD_VAL
18059           1134        R10
18059           1234        R3
18061           1111        R5
```

to look like that:

```
id      CANT_VAL    COD_VAL
18059   18.56       R12
18059   1134        R10
18059   1234        R3
18060   11          R10
18061   15          R11
18061   1111        R5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a `GROUP BY`, but `UNION`:

```
select * from cant
union
select * from col
order by id, cant_val;
```

Comment: Perhaps UNION ALL, depending on how you want to deal with duplicates.